# How to download file in java from a url which is in javascript

Tags: javascript, java, download

I generally scrape or download files from java using JSoup. I have this url which has javascript (javascript:__doPostBack('btnLink_Excel','')) and I dont know a way to download in java. What I am trying to do is download the excel file from the link http://www.mcxindia.com/SitePages/BhavCopyDateWise.aspx

Any pointers/help would make my day.

View In Excel

Comment: Short answer is: **you can't**. You need to actually run the JavaScript in the context of the page (in this case, run the _doPostBack function on that page). This is a common technique against crawlers.

Comment: So, is there anyway it can be automated?, I mean in Javascript or anyother language?

Comment: If you run an 'actual' browser which can run javascript (e.g. phantom.js), then you should be able to get the link.

Comment: Thank you for the input. I guess I need to do something in Selenium